# Compiling a for statement from BASIC to C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm writing a compiler to migrate some legacy VB6 program to C++. I need to translate a `for` statement in the VB6 language into a C++ `for` statement:

```
For var = start To end Step S
  ...
Next var
```

The naive translation will not work since `S` might be negative:

```
for (var = start; var <= end; var += S)
```

I've came up with this translation but the ternary `if` in the condition is ugly:

```
for (var = start; (S > 0) ? (var <= end) : (var >= end); var += S)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Did you mean at compile time??

Comment: If your `step` is a negative value, then adding it to `start` will decrease the value, just as a positive value will increase it.

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes, it's a dialect of BASIC ! :(

Comment: @OnlineCop Yes. How can I prettify the output of this conversion?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've updated the question text.

Comment: "The naive translation will not work since S might be negative" -- Assuming BASIC `for` loops work the way I think they do, that's incorrect. The "naive" translation should work just fine. Try it.

Comment: @OnlineCop: the problem is not the `+=`, the problem is the `<=`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: `for i = 10 to 1 step -1` would be translated as `for (int i = 10; i <= 1; i += -1)`, which should have `>=` instead.

Comment: Well BASIC dialects are too many. When I first use BASIC it was not "end for" but "NEXT" statement indicating end of loop.

Comment: Is it legal (and finite) in your language to say `FOR I = 0 TO (INT_MAX) STEP 1000` ?  (substituting in the `INT_MAX` value for your C++ compiler)

Comment: @XiaogeSu: And the `NEXT` was followed by the name of the variable and you did not have to nest them properly and could have more than one next for each loop and such.

Comment: @JanHudec: In the Apple ][ dialect I was using, the NEXT does not need the variable name followed, but the performance will be better if it is followed. Good old days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a generated code. You'll only ever be looking at it when debugging the code generator. So it's totally irrelevant if it's ugly. It only matters if it is correct and then the simpler it is to generate, the better.

---

Update: However, if it's a migration, it might indeed make sense to try to make the code readable. Then I'd either:

1. Resolve the operator to use in the translator if possible, since the step is almost always constant.
2. Hide the logic in auxiliary definition and use a range-based for:

   ```
   for(auto var : basic_range(start, end, S))
   ```

   Unfortunately [boost::irange](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) did not make it to C++11 and it is defined using half-open range as usual for C++, i.e. `end` is not included while you want to include it. So you have to define the range yourself. Basically you'd just hide the direction logic in it, so it does not obscure the code. Look at the [boost::irange](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) for inspiration.

The largest issue would be object lifecycle anyway. VB6 (unlike earlier BASICs) is managed. So you'll probably end up using smart pointers for most things and it's not the most efficient thing to do.

Comment: Exactly, why would it matter, I can only assume the C++ is just way of getting the pesudo code into a native binary

Comment: Actully is a migration. I'm writing a compiler to translate the legacy code to C++ code.

Comment: Not really a compiler then, more a translator

Comment: @paulm I have a tokenizer, an abstract tree, an expression evaluator and a output text. It is a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a ternary expression in the termination condition if you multiply `var` and `end` by the sign of `S`

```
int sign = S>=0 ? 1 : -1;
for (int var = start; sign*var <= sign*end; var += S)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: True, but now you've created brand-new problems.  Multiplication by `-1` may overflow.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Extremely unlikely, but true

Comment: Thank you on the answer. I've upgraded all the datatypes from 16 bits (VB) to 32 bits (C++), so in theory this should not overflow.